# How is racecondition possible between the process?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, race-condition

I understand that race condition is possible between threads because they are operating on the same Data.

So in my CS course I learned that the main difference between process and thread is that thread is lightweight Process in sense that the Data that is being operated on is not copied, but that the thread simply gets cpu time, but operates on the same Data as some other thread, which makes sense why race condition is possible, but how can race condition be possible with process, the course states that this is possible becauese of the shared Data, but how can Data be share between 2 processes if the process gets its own "Block" within which it operates, shared ressources would mean we have threads and not a process:

```
void forkexample{
     pid_t pid = fork()
     if (pid == 0){
         printf ("Hello from Child! /n");
     }
     else
     {
        printf ("Hello from Parent! child has pid = %d /n", pid);
     }
}
```

the child process that will be created is basically a deep copy of the parent Process so how can deep copy cause race conditions?

```
Parent Process:
------------------
CPU States        |
Memory block      |
other ressources  |
------------------

Child Process completaly new block contaning same code and initial states, 
but is completaly new Block in which it operates i.e Data is copied etc.
so how can race condition happen here?
------------------
CPU States        |
Memory block      |
other ressources  |
------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `fork` happens, the standard allocated memory is not shared by default (operating systems typically use a copy-on-write approach in practice for the sake of performance). However, the memory can be manually/explicitly shared using the `mmap` system call. Because of this, race condition are still possible. Moreover, there are still several shared resources on mainstream machines that can generally be shared between processes by default. A good example is the file system : if two processes read/write the same file without any lock or synchronization, then there is likely a race condition.